# Adding multiple values to multiple rows in nodejs mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a table that holds products and a column for total amount sold (amount_sold), after an order has gone through I want to add the value bought to this column. 
I have an array that will look like:

```
[{sku: "SKU1", purchased: 1},
{sku: "SKU2", purchased: 2}],
```

For multiple updates normally there's

```
UPDATE product SET (?) WHERE sku_id in (?)
```

but I want to add the purchased to the amount sold column somthing like:

```
UPDATE product  SET amount_sold = amount_sold + 1 WHERE sku_id in (?)
```

Obviously a customer might not purchase 1 of everything they buy. Would I have to do a loop through a array to add these values? Or is there a way to do it in one query?
Thanks

Comment: Interesting the SQL you say works looks wrong and the one you say does not work looks right.  No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should look like:

```
UPDATE product
SET amount_sold = amount_sold + 
    CASE sku_id
        WHEN ? THEN ?
        WHEN ? THEN ?
        ...
    END
WHERE sku_id IN (?)
```

Since the number of `WHEN` clauses varies, you'll need to build this dynamically.

```js
let purchases = [{
  sku: "SKU1",
  purchased: 1
}, {
  sku: "SKU2",
  purchased: 2
}];
let whens = "WHEN ? THEN ? ".repeat(purchases.length);
let sql = `UPDATE product 
    SET amount_sold = amount_sold + 
        CASE sku_id ${whens} END
    WHERE sku_id IN (?)`;
let params = [],
  skus = [];
purchases.forEach(({sku, purchased}) => {
  params.push(sku, purchased);
  skus.push(sku);
});
params.push(skus);
db.query(sql, params, function(res, error) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to reply, works perfectly thank you!